# How to implement button from twitter "following" page

Tags: android

everyone.
I'm trying to make button like on the twitter page, where you can unfollow a person.
It has 3 options: "Following" when we already following, "Unfollow" when mouse is over this button and "Follow" to add a person.
I'm trying to use Toggle button and  tag with 3 items inside. But can I also change the text selector or just picture?
Any suggestions how to do this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Damluar,

I believe the `<item>` elements of a `<selector>` can only reference `drawables`.  See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#selector-element

So, ff you include the text as part of the button images `drawable` then you just change between the 3 `drawables` in your `<selector>` and don't worry about managing text changes as well.